# Small "hic" with a 301 htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

i would like simply to create a 301 redirect, but my code does'nt work and returns a beautiful 404 page (-_-).

I think the problem is the "?" in the from url, i tried to escape it but it doesn't work anymore.

```
RewriteRule ^produit.php?PDT_ID=473 /product.php?id_product=210 [R=301]
```

Thanks to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common mistake. As the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) say, to test for things in the query string, you need to use a RewriteCond directive, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PDT_ID=473
RewriteRule ^produit.php /product.php?id_product=210 [R=301]
```

Which means "if the query string matches the pattern 'PDT_ID=473', and the pattern matches the uri, then rewrite". Note that you might want to make the rewriteCond's regex more foolproof to ensure it won't match things like APDT_ID=4735 as well, but this should get you started.

Comment: I just change you code adding a $

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PDT_ID=473$
RewriteRule ^produit.php /product.php?id_product=210 [R=301]

because if i replace 473 by 47333 or 473987 or 473000 ... it redirects the page always to /product.php?id_product=210

Comment: @JojoLapin45, a better way is to use the `\b` delimiter `\bPDT_ID=473\b` -- that way, if another parameter is present, the cond will still match.